A world without entropy
Is it possible to fathom a reality without any entropy? How would it be different to our world, both in the underlying physical laws*, and the way it manifests (objectively and subjectively)?

In order to somewhat focus this, let's aim for a reality as similar to ours as possible, e.g. "4 dimensional spacetime", some sort of "atomic", "mass", "energy" etc. Only drop things from our own reality that absolutely need to be dropped for this to work.
* if the answer is "no conceivable physical laws can achieve this", then I don't want to just limit solutions to requiring only physical laws. Feel free to insert something novel

Not clear to me what you mean by "without entropy". (And do you allow an empty "universe"?) A universe consisting of only one single elementary particle could be a universe without entropy (if the particle has no states). But a universe with more than one (distinguishable) particle would "have entropy" just by the definition of "entropy"  (even though the entropy could theoretically be 0 J/K).

@mudskipper see my second paragraph for limits to the question, which rule out your suggestions. Imagine a world where nothing ever decays, perpetual motion machines are the norm, the sun never burns out. Is such a world a complete fantasy, only possible if some omnipotent being is controlling it? Or is there actually a way to conceive of such a world naturally?

I don't believe such a world is possible - it's a pure fantasy. Impossible meaning: it's not possible to have a consistent mathematical model representing such a world. "Entropy" seems to me an extremely basic notion (but I don't really know much about physics).

I mean: To conceive it as "possible" we would have to drop practically all of physics (thermodynamics). In particular: No atomic theory in whatever form. Lots of simple questions would become inexplicable (why does rubbing my hands make them warmer; how is it that stone steps after a century of use show the imprints of shuffling steps - see: Lucretius De Rerum Naturae). Everything would become: magic.

@mudskipper I think you might be right. Of course I'd like others' inputs, but you seem to be on to a sensible answer, even better if you can back it up formally

I'll leave a more elaborate answer to others - I just don't know enough about physics :)

"without entropy" makes no sense. Entropy is the probability for a certain state of things to be the case. As long as there are things that can be in a certain state, they will have entropy. Even a world were entropy does not increase doesn't make sense: it's equivalent to a world were the most probable states are not happening, and therefore they would not be more probable.

I think this could potentially be answered on Physics.SE (maybe if reframed as something like "what assumptions are required for a system to have entropy"?) and would get interesting answers there

The world as a single unchanging whole, as argued by the pre-Socratic Parmenides.

To emphasise Armand's point, not only might the most probable states not happen, but the most improbable and bizarre states could happen. All the air molecules in the room where you are sitting could spontaneously collect in one corner and leave you suffocating in a vacuum. Half the blood in your body could boil while the other half freezes. Dead and decomposed people could come back to life. Chemical reactions could all go in reverse. In practice, all of this is impossible. Only a totally non-differentiated Parmenidean world could lack entropy.

@RabbiKaii I hope you did take a look at my answer, because I think it is the most promising and also versatile answer especially the first answer. Its been a week now and i don't think there is a much more straight-forward answer (i.e., no.1 of my answer), I just hope that if you deem it good enough that you would accept the answer.

@Howwhye I remembered liking it but I will read it again and all the others when I have time, and then decide which to accept

@armand What do you think of my answer? Do you think it is a viable solution and is in accordance to the definition of entropy or is it just a deceptive way of answering the question by twisting definitions?

@RabbiKaii Did you by any chance glance over all the answers, I really want to hear your viewpoint. I would really appreciate if you could interact with the responses you have gotten so far.

@Howwhye please be patient. I will get round to it, but I am extremely busy at the moment and I can't do anything about it. It might take a while but I will not neglect this - I never do

@RabbiKaii I will hold you to your word.

@RabbiKaii I am very sorry to hear about your loss. It must be really tough for you to go through this, I hope you find the courage to pass through this time. Take however long you want, please don't feel pressured by my comment. Again, I am sorry if I made you feel that way.

@RabbiKaii No problem, I don't really even know why I am caught up on it. Take however long you want to be honest.

A world without entropy means giving up the arrow of time. For me, the objective measure of the passage of time (despite of spacetime being relative) is the arrow of time which is dependent on entropy.
Assuming, entropy is an in-built feature of the universe and is not mind-dependent but is an integral part of the workings of this universe. I think the only two possible universes are:

A universe that is identical to ours but is actually a snapshot of our universe at any given point in spacetime and doesn't actually progress from then on, i.e., a snapshot of our universe at a specific time t, a universe without time or movement, a universe slice within the time cone, a static universe. There is only one possible state of the system because that is the only one there is. (very imaginary and absurd)

An "ideal" finite universe in that there is only one non-discretized (i.e., no quanta of energy) "perfect insulator", where there is no heat transfer what so ever because the internal kinetic energy can not have multiple states as energy is not contained in quanta but energy is simply contained within the perfect insulator as  a whole and there is no lose of energy or interaction with the universe through radiation as it is a "perfect insulator". One could think of this perfect insulator as "the smallest indivisible particle that has the characteristics of a perfect insulator".


Alternative

We don't know what was at the beginning of the universe accurately, but only at fractions that are approximately at 0, but at t=0 would be the exact opposite of the heat death (which is characterized by the maximum entropy that could be achieved) thus at t=0, the universe might have actually had an entropic value so low i.e., intuitively zero - as a starting point (speculative), thus in a way we could say there is no entropy but I don't think it would satisfy the condition of a world because a singularity is not a world or a universe.

Unconventional example

Another distinct unconventional example is the heat death of the universe where it wouldn't make sense to actually use entropy as there is no more thermodynamic process that will take place but actually in such a state entropy is at its maximum that it could possibly be in and if you think that entropy is useless as a physical model to understand any phenomena at this stage you can say that entropy is deemed useless and therefore not considered within your physical framework. This example is more like a loop-hole to ignore entropy as it yields no use for further discussion, a philosophical dead-end, if you may.

P.S: The first example actually consists everything that our universe has and is pretty much identical, it has a 4-dimensional spacetime, atomic structures, mass and energy. The second universe is an extra example that leverages the lack of atomic structure, discrete quantized states and quantity of objects for the directional flow of  "time" and motion, it seems more unrestricted.

I think the first one is astute, if you don't have time you don't have 'equilibrium'. The second one, a classic example of entropy is 'pool balls on a table' where pool balls being randomly confined to half the table is significantly less likely than being evenly scattered across the whole table. and I don't think that depends on inelastic collisions, just a sufficiently large number of balls with initial velocities?

@Kaia I think the collisions have to be perfectly elastic because the loss of energy would lead to a loss of momentum given enough time, the collisions wouldn't continue indefinitely, at some point all of the kinetic energy will become sound and heat. It is inevitable given an inelastic condition and very intuitive.

My point is that not even perfectly elastic collisions save us. An ideal gas has entirely perfectly elastic collisions but certainly has thermodynamics and entropy happening.

@Kaia Yes, but that is exactly why I pointed out no quanta, if you think about it the statistical transfer and arrangement of heat happens starting from the atomic level and thus by abandoning the usual quantum mechanical transfer of heat I have avoided the need for entropy i.e., the statistical component of entropy. Thermodynamics is happening just not entropy.

again my point is that quantization, nondeterminism, etc are all explicitly not required for entropy--you can have entropy without quanta, without friction, etc. 'Initially, there are objects of different temperatures, and later, they've equalized temperatures' is entropy, since temperature is the partial derivative of internal energy wrt entropy

Why take the +1 away? My first answer is a very viable one.

@Howwhye The "randomness" and probabilistic distribution used in entropy dont require non-determinism.  When we're looking at a large scale, it's just easier to take averages instead of trying to compute the interactions of an extremely large number of interacting particles.  Consider sound.  We can model it deterministically, but because the way it spreads out from the source, you're not going to see a noise travel in reverse, towards a single point in space in a way that creates the reverse of whatever generated the sound.

@Howwhye How is that related to determinism?  Entropy doesnt only exist with true randomness.  You can create deterministic models where thermodynamics emerges with entropy.  The constant collision of large numbers of atoms is just practically impossible to calculate due to the sheer number of interactions, so we look at it as a bulk and treat it as random collisions because it's easier to model what happens on average than to model what happens exactly for individual interacting particles.  It's also not clear why you suggest qualification of energy allows randomness to exist.

@JMac In this sense, entropy, as a measure of disorder or the number of possible microstates, would have no room to increase or even be defined meaningfully after equilibrium is reached. The concept of entropy is deeply tied to the imperfections, irreversibilities, and statistical behaviors present in our actual universe, all of which are absent in my idealized scenario.

@Howwhy Do you have a background in physics?  A lot of this sounds almost non-sensical to me.  Your description of the universe 2 in your answer has self-discrepancies.  When you model gas as a bunch of balls flying around and hitting against each other without friction or energy loss (which is how you describe universe 2) then you actually just wind up modeling temperature and heat transfer.  Temperature of a gas is proportional to the average kinetic energy of individual molecules interacting perfectly elastically with other objects.

@JMac I do have a pretty good background in physics. I guess you are right, I was just thinking of the individual objects and how entropy would work within the individual objects being considered systems. You are definitely right and my second model i.e., example 2 is actually not a great example at all.

@Kaia Sorry for the misconception, you were right, I wasn't considering the universe as an even larger system and I was purely focused on the thermodynamic arrangement of heat within the objects, I hope my new example is more aligned and correct with all definitions of entropy.

The concept of ideal perpetual motion is ancient. Aristotle argued that the stars, planets, and Sun are in perpetual circular motion around the earth. He argued that an invisible boundary must exist between the heavens and the earth somewhere inside the orbit of the moon. Objects set in motion eventually come to rest on earth. The nature of motion in the heavens was distinct from the nature of motion on the earth.
To my knowledge Galileo was the first person to apply the ideal model of perpetual motion, which I call the counter-factual, to the motion of objects on earth as well as in the heavens. He said that a ball projected at initial speed along an infinite horizontal plane would continue at uniform speed in the absence of resistance. Galileo knew that a ball moves at constant horizontal speed, just after it exits a smooth inclined ramp, at least for the first few ticks of his pendulum clock. He applied the ideal counterfactual reasoning, the absence of resistive force on Earth, that informs what we now call Newton's first law of motion. Newton held that a body remains at constant uniform speed unless it is acted upon by an external force. Newton generalizes Galileo's previous model specifying the absence of resistance to horizontal motion.
Ring a bell in an ideal universe (with no entropy) and it will ring forever. We call this an ideal oscillator. Resonant systems convert kinetic energy to potential energy in a cyclic periodic process. In the absence of entropy no physical attribute would manifest that acts to attenuate the conservative energy states of resonant systems.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/179353/if-a-bell-is-rung-in-a-perfect-vacuum-and-is-suspended-by-opposing-magnets-will
The frictionless incline plane, or ideal roller coaster models, inform the historical development of the work-energy theorem. Work is vector force acting through a distance with calculation methods from the Calculus. The work of a conservative force corresponds to a change in energy state of the system, and in theory the energy stored in the system can be converted to another round of work. In an ideal universe energy would always be available, in theory, to convert to more forms of work, that is, 100% of all thermal and non-thermal energy should be available to convert to a new round of work provided humans can develop an appropriate apparatus or observe a natural work-energy transformation. I don't know if resistive forces would disappear altogether without entropy. For example, would it be like walking on slick ice instead of getting traction? I think in a world without entropy the heat due to friction or loss could exist but then in theory it could always be recovered 100% as another round of work done by an ideal heat engine. I have heard arguments that friction would be impossible without entropy. But entropy is derived from friction and the irreversible loss of conservative energy sources available to perform further rounds of work that humans find valuable or that we observe in a natural work-energy transformation process.
https://www.visionlearning.com/en/library/Physics/24/Energy/46

In Joule's famous "paddle wheel" experiment he used a falling weight to pull a string that turned a paddle wheel submerged in a bucket of water. Joule found that the mechanical energy released by the falling weight was converted into heat energy by the paddle wheel. Joule measured the amount of heat energy absorbed by the water by recording the temperature of the water before and after the paddle wheel began moving (temperature is a way to measure heat energy and is discussed in the Temperature lesson). Joule found that the increase in water temperature was directly related to the amount of kinetic energy released. Joule thus showed that an exact relationship governs the conversion of one form of energy into another.

The first law of thermodynamics holds that heat, work, and energy are equivalent, and work equals the change in conservative energy plus the transfer of heat. In the Joule apparatus the work is performed by a falling weight in Earth's gravity. The potential energy of the weight converts to kinetic energy that drives a paddle wheel which increases the temperature of a fluid inside a container with little or no loss of heat through the walls of the container. In a universe without entropy the process could go in reverse. The heat in the fluid would somehow drive the paddle wheel which would lift the weight. Similar mechanisms would occur for all modes of energy transformation between heat and other defined forms of energy if there is no natural tendency for heat to flow only from a higher temperature hot source to a lower temperature cold sink. I don't know if I can imagine all the perceptive and scientific implications but I have thought that resonance of the universe is akin to the Voice of God.

Some people have said that the sound of OM / AUM represents the sound of the movement in creation. It can in some circumstances seem quite perceptible.

No. Your system has moving parts (something like atoms with energy), so it has more than one possible state. If a system has more than one possible state, there is nonzero Gibbs entropy by definition.

where p_i is the probability of finding the system in a possible state i, S is entropy.
Therefore it is definitionally impossible, exactly like a world without distances which has objects in different places. The possibility of different laws of physics doesn't even play into it.

+1 Well stated and precise. In my super-generalized understanding, entropy = possible microstates.

@Howwhye entropy is related to possible microstates by the above proportion (and a constant of proportionality). They're not equal, just closely related.

Yeah, I didn't have the proportionality sign that is why I used =, I guess I could have use a close second "~".

+1 S=0 means there is only one "perfect" state. The entropy of a fair coin toss that has heads on both sides of the coin is zero.

@IdiosyncraticSoul +1 a great example.

I can think of two cases.
In a computer game, like a VR environment, the physics are set by the game engine, and entropy is not included. So it's possible to have a virtual realm without entropy, though it causally depends on our entropic realm. The interesting case then is, what if our experiences are in some kind of simulation, and the apparent consistency of conservation laws/symmetries is provided only by a computational engine?
The other example is if/when all the matter in the cosmos has decayed into photons. Photons don't experience time. According to Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Cosmology, this time-free maximum-entropy photon soup, would be conformally equivalent to the Big Bang, a state of minimum entropy and the smallest scale.

Right, I was imagining the word "Roku" bouncing around the TV screen. In the photon soup case, the universe would be a lot bigger than in the Big Bang... Infinitely bigger. It would be the big fuzz. Like static on an analog TV. So there you have it: TV is a world without entropy!

The photon soup during the big bang is maximum-entropy thus you are still saying that entropy exists at the maximum level such a universe is not entropy-free but full of entropy from your perspective. I think you want to see minimal entropy photon soup.

@Howwhye: The large photon soup, would according to Penrose, be conformally equivalent to the small Big Bang, because time has ceased in a cosmos with only spacetime & light. This lack of time, & time's arrow, is the indicator entropy has ceased to be meaningful & hence the violation of the 2nd Law of Thermodynamics is possible. K? The photon soup in a sense exists for infinite time, with a conformal horizon, like the switch between bulk & boundary in the AdS-CFT correspondence

(I am not a physicist, take this all with a grain of salt)
At its heart, entropy is just a measure of the number of possible microscopic states for a set of macroscopic variables.
That means it depends on the assumption that macroscopic variables (temperature, pressure, mass, number of particles, etc) can sufficiently describe a system without knowing the positions, velocities, etc of every individual component within it. This is essentially the concept of thermodynamic equilibrium: systems tend to reach a point where, from the perspective of the entire system, 'nothing happens'.
In particular, the idea is that, for particular values of macroscopic variables, there's bazillions of possible particle configurations that would yield those macroscopic variables, and the particular configuration is constantly changing as particles bounce into each other. So if you know the previous microscopic configuration and wait long enough, it doesn't give you any information into the current microscopic state--they're all equally likely.
As an analogy: if you're in a casino playing blackjack, the cards remaining in the deck depend on the cards that have already been seen, so the 'macroscopic' description of the game ("4 decks, dealer stands on 17, blackjacks pay 3:2") is insufficient to describe everything that's important to the system. However, for roulette, knowing where the ball fell the last 1000 times will not (in an ideal case) give you any indication what happens next--the macroscopic state (the rules of roulette) describes the system.
Because of that, entropy of a system is only defined when a system is in (or close to) thermodynamic equilibrium. So if you put a cold block of ice on a hot metal grill inside a box, the box as a whole doesn't have an 'entropy' in the same way it doesn't have a 'temperature'--if you say "the average temperature of an atom in the box is 50 degrees C", that's an insufficient description of the box as a whole, because half of it is ice and half of it is hot metal.
Of course, you could consider a small section of the ice as a system in a particular moment in time, very close to thermodynamic equilibrium with its neighbours, and find the entropy there. There's times where that doesn't work either; The light from a laser is not in thermodynamic equilibrium and doesn't have an entropy or a temperature (at least not in standard thermodynamics).
The other complication is: entropy isn't a "real thing" , it's a model. So the question isn't whether it exists, but if the model is useful somewhere. But if the question is "what's a world where the model of entropy doesn't apply?", the answer can be either "this world, right now" or "you can find some way to use a sufficiently modified version of entropy to analyze basically anything".
As an example: if you have a perfectly deterministic universe with classical mechanics, you can describe its evolution over time without invoking entropy or temperature at all. And if you knew its initial state you could compute its exact state at a later time. (No entropy required.) However, you could also describe it in terms of entropy, and indeed the behaviour of ideal gasses in classical mechanics is extremely well-described by statistical mechanics. (Entropy exists.)

To get a situation where 'entropy' isn't a useful model, I suspect you're going to have to get rid of the idea of thermodynamic equilibrium. That's not that bad--again, we just need a world where macroscopic quantities are insufficient to describe the statistical behaviour of systems.
So e.g. if you had a world where there's two particles, A and B with slightly different properties, and 60 seconds after an A particle is created, it spontaneously turns into a B particle, and vice versa 60 seconds after a B is born it turns into an A. Then specifying all the macroscopic quantities (temperature, pressure, mass, number of A particles, number of B particles, other types of particles) is insufficient to describe the system. We'd additionally need to know the age distribution of the particles (how soon would they switch). And that might not be enough--the age distribution might be different in different regions of the system, if e.g. A's were heavier than B's.
I guess the point is, by one measure, a world where entropy doesn't 'work' needs to be very different from our world, since it messes with things like conservation of energy or the thermodynamic arrow of time. At the same time, it doesn't need to be deterministic, timeless, entirely ordered or entirely chaotic, or have no friction/dissipation. It just needs to have something "annoying" that doesn't reduce nicely into a measurement about a system as a whole.

I agree that entropy is a model and not a real thing but whatever characteristics this model seems to have is constantly observed in nature constantly by us humans and so I think a proper way of handling this question is creating a universe in which such characteristics don't arise, it seems like an easy feat to achieve, remove probabilistic distribution and any phenomena that seems to display such a behavior.

This answer on Physics SE describes entropy of an expanding gas using any reversible process necessary to restore the gas to its original properties: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/527438/entropy-change-in-the-free-expansion-of-a-gas. The reversible process would occur at a constant temperature and dissipate heat to the surroundings even though the original expansion of the gas dissipates no heat or change of temperature. In a world without entropy it seems the ideal gas would not expand its volume over time when considered as an isolated system.

"entropy is just a measure of the number of possible microscopic states for a set of macroscopic variables" ... No, this is not at all what entropy is, or else the same system would always have the same entropy. You have mentioned half of the definition.

@DanielAsimov What's the half that I'm missing, to you?

You ask:

Is it possible to fathom a reality without any entropy?

Absolutely. Before entropy was discovered, fathoming reality got on quite well; many people still fathom reality unaware of it's "existence". Even if we grant entropy is real as part of our scientific realism, do we use it when dealing with the reality of driving to work or the reality of growing vegetables in our gardens? We might even ask ourselves, is our reality nothing more than a series of representations that are merely useful tools, mere instruments of thought as proposed by scientific instrumentalism. Perhaps our model of the world is diminished a bit in terms of explanation or prediction, but with or without entropy, we can still enjoy a rich reality. Our theories of entropy are simply a map of how physical reality works, so make sure you do not confuse the map for the territory.

Engineers would compare the mind to software and the embodied brain to hardware. Body (hardware) has minimal physiological needs. Mind (software) generates an apparently unlimited desire to possess, consume, and enjoy the output from natural and social production. Social intercourse (mothering, fathering, peer interactions) may seem scarce or abundant. Economic scarcity is the idea that production (hardware) cannot support unlimited consumption so scarce resources must be allocated to coordinate production and consumption. Money is software: it does not appear in the laws of thermodynamics.

@SystemTheory Absolutely. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/

I like your answer and the article you posted. But I think you have taken a "software" focus that merely asserts the obvious fact that we have the ability to fathom reality before we understood the concept of entropy. The question is can we imagine an alternative universe in which the "hardware" operates without the thermodynamic attributes of entropy? I think humans were motivated to develop the concept of entropy due to our desire to perform useful work using machinery and due to the expense of burning scarce fuel. Software (mind, desire) drives investigation of hardware (physical laws).

the question asked explicitly. So, the OP cannot improve the question and make it more meaningful before they understand what it means to use the word 'reality'. That's the help I'm offering.

I agree that reality is a model in our minds. We take entropy to be a factual or true attribute of reality in part because scientists and engineers evoke the concept to build and understand machines that generate a flow of high temperature heat to perform work and dissipate waste heat to a lower temperature sink. One does not always think of entropy as a property of reality while driving one's car. But the internal combustion engine, brakes, and physical models take entropy as factual. Maybe we can imagine a counter-factual reality without entropy and maybe we cannot given factual imagination.

One has to distinguish the physical reality and the human concepts used to describe this reality. Reality is out there, regardless of whether we describe it or not. Thus, entropy, energy, etc. are merely human concepts. Asking what the world would be like without entropy is like asking what a pile of money would be like, if we didn't count it - it will still be out there.
In a sense, entropy is the opposite to what we mean when asking, whether a falling tree still makes a sound, if there is no one to hear it. The tree still makes a sound - if we mean the compressions and the dilutions of air, which are independent of the presence of an observer. However, it doesn't sing a swan song or emit a death cry, because these are characteristics attributed to it by a poetically inclined observer - they are not inherent to the tree or sound themselves. So entropy is something that makes sense to humans, but which does not exist outside of human imagination.

I agree and you are right but the reason we developed or brought up the human concept of entropy is because there are some properties or characteristics physical reality seems to portray to us and this properties we observe and measure we call "entropy". So, you are saying despite of the human concept of entropy was discovered or not, the characteristics of reality that we deem "entropy" will still exist, right? So, I guess the question asks what if these characteristics of reality weren't present, they will always be present (bc reality) and that is why the question is a thought experiment!

Any "characteristics of reality" is a human concept, because we choose to characterize it. And concepts are not discovered - they are invented. One discovers something that actually exists (like discovering America), whereas inventions are a product of human mind (like steam engine or communism.) Reality would change, if we remove something that is actually out there - electromagnetic field, particles, gravity - these are also concepts, but much closer approximating actual things. Entropy is too abstract.

You see you said EM fields and gravity are concepts even though they are closer to approximating reality. I think entropy is as much a concept as every other physical characteristics you mentioned, I don't understand why you think it is 'too' abstract. Is temperature also too abstract? Or do you think temperature belongs with gravity and EM fields?

@Howwhye so what would the world be like without temperature? The question is meaningless, because temperature is not something that one can take out from the world. The only difference between temperature and entropy is that everyone has experience with temperature, while entropy is attributed some mystical significance. Indeed, even physicists are often confused about it - because entropy may mean several different things, which are not quite clarified in physics curricula.

Entropy is, roughly speaking, the tendency of a thermodynamic system to tend away from order towards chaos. This was discovered, not invented. There might be alternate realities where this doesn't happen. That's what I am asking.

@RabbiKaii this is not correct. Thermodynamics states that a system evolves towards thermodynamic equilibrium, which might actually be rather ordered- e.g., when all the spins align in a ferromagnet. Mechanics however tells us that the inverse movement is equally possible, which is not the case - that is time reversibility is broken. To describe this mathematically Gibbs and Clausius invented a quantity called entropy, which by definition can only increase for the processes that are observed in thermodynamics.

@RabbiKaii Chaos/disorder are just laymen terms to refer to a macroscopic state that is described by more microscopic configurations and hence more likely. Like the waters of the Red sea closing is much more likely than them opening - because there are more arrangements of water molecules corresponding to the see without a hole in the middle.

As enlightening as these facts are, like you admit, these processes do happen in a certain way in our universe for reasons, which involve complications like probability, exceptions and more. Nonetheless, they happen. There might be a way to make a universe, tweaking this and that, so that they don't happen. I am just asking about that and it doesn't need to get too complicated

@RogerV. People have experience with love and feel it, even though "love" is a concept and abstract, so based on such descriptions how would you interpret an abstract concept like entropy? I understand that entropy and love are of different categories but I am just using love as an example because you said "temperature is something you can experience" so it is much different than entropy.

@RabbiKaii I am with you on this. I don't think the question is too complicated, to be honest. I think there are differences in definitions with some people in this community, that is all.

@RabbiKaii or at least the values given to the definitions of concepts.

I am not discussing the human experience but the nature of reality. I don't think entropy is only in the category of human experience (and even then, is certainly not a qualia)

@Howwhye I don't see how love is relevant here : the question is not about how humans would feel/behave, if Clausius and Gibbs had never invented entropy - it is about how the actual physical world would be like... fi certain abstract concept didn't exist.

@RabbiKaii yes, the processes happen in the universe for reasons - but concepts like entropy, temperature, pressure describe something that results from behavior of millions of atoms/molecules, which move according to the laws of (quantum mechanics), interact via various forces, etc. Which of these do you change, when you talk about "world without entropy"? If you want to change a specific component - you need to ask a more specific question, without muddying it with all the entropy talk... as is, the question is akin to asking: "If the world were not the way it is, what would it be like?"

It is a mistake to address "a world without entropy", because in such case you are targeting "a world where S=0", which is a system at 0k (zero degrees Kelvin), the convention specified by the Third Law of Thermodynamics. Boring. What you probably mean is "a world where dS=0", a world where changes in entropy are zero. This answer goes in such sense. So,
Yes.
The world where entropy change is zero does exist: it is this world, but not as a human individual experiences it.
The world without entropy change is this world, at any instant, without time flowing. Like when you take a picture.
Of course, as humans, we cannot experience a state where time does not flow. But such static configuration occurs at any instant.
In an instant, there is no possibility for entropy to change, that is dS/dt=0 (that is change related to (t)ime).
Q: What happens with energy when time stops?
In the form dS=dQ/T, notice that the smaller the temperature for the same heat, the larger entropy is. So, in simple terms, entropy means energy dispersal. But be careful: it is energy dispersal in relation to the system potential, not in relation to the system evolution.
A: So, energy cannot disperse when time does not flow (this is a simplistic approach for this application, so, please bear with me), because, under such perspective, energy depends on time to manifest.
For example, temperature is, in some way, a form of energy. What is temperature? Essentially, elastic molecular vibration, kinetic energy. When time stops, molecules stop vibrating, but are still loaded with elastic energy (which would be potential energy). So, when time stops, kinetic energy can be understood as potential energy. There is energy, but it cannot manifest.
Such is the difference of a world with dS=0 (where time does not flow, but where particles have energy, which waits for time to manifest), and a world with S=0 (where time flows, but particles have lost all energy*).
*... which is paradoxical, because particles are energy. That's essentially why 0k is impossible in real life.

A deterministic universe would be without entropy. There would be no statistics (everything happens with infinite precision), no probabilities (everything happens with absolute certainty) and therefore no thermodynamics or quantum mechanics.
Despite this a deterministic universe is easy to imagine. It would consist of classical mechanics only, a well-oiled mechanism operating with infinite precision.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
